# Where are closures values stored in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope, reference, closures

Code example with a closure:

```
const Component = () => {
    let counter = 0;
    
    const logger = () => {
        console.log(counter);
    }

    setTimeout(() => counter = counter + 10, 1000);

    return logger;
}

const myLogger = Component();

myLogger(); // output after ~1s: 10
```

When a closure is created, where are the closure values stored in memory?

In my example, after `Component` returns, its execution context is deleted, and so is its `variable environment`. But `myLogger` still holds a reference to `counter` in its `[[Scopes]]` property.

Where is the value of this reference located? Is it in the global execution context or is it where?

Comment: Counter in this case is code-block scoped; so when the code is finished running it'll enter garbage collection to be deleted shortly after when idle or when need is dire.

It will lose reference/memory for it soon or at least mark itself in sectors as available.

Answer (score 0):

Closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time in JavaScript. The closure values are stored in the environment it was defined in.This environment consists of any local variables that were in-scope at the time the closure was created.

For more info check [JavaScript Variable Scope and Closure](https://javascript.info/closure)

I hope this would help you.